# When $\sqrt{(x, Ax)}$ is a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, when can a matrix $A$ be turned into a norm $||x||^2 = (x,Ax)$?

I have already realized that when $A$ is symmetric and its eigenvalues are strictly positive, $(x,Ax)$ is a norm. But I'm not sure if these are the most general conditions.

Comment: It is never a norm, because $(\lambda x, A \lambda x) = \lambda^2 (x, Ax) \neq \lambda (x, Ax)$ for $x$ with $(x, Ax) \neq 0$ and $\lambda \notin \{0,1\}$.

Comment: You need a square root, $\sqrt{(x,Ax)}$ is (potentially) a norm, not $(x,Ax)$.

Comment: Oh sorry! I'll fix it

Comment: In $\Bbb R^n$, it is sufficient to have $\frac 12 (A + A^*)$ be positive definite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write every matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ in a unique way as the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix,

$$A = \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2}(A+A^T)}_{S} + \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2}(A - A^T)}_{T}.$$

Now, for a skew-symmetric matrix $T$, we have $(x,Tx) = (-Tx,x) = -(x,Tx)$, so $(x,Tx) = 0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus only the symmetric part of the matrix matters. And if $\lVert x\rVert := \sqrt{(x,Ax)}$ is a norm, the symmetric part of $A$ must be positive definite, for otherwise we'd have $\lVert x\rVert = 0$ for some nonzero $x$ (and $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ would even attain imaginary values if the symmetric part is indefinite).

So a necessary and sufficient condition for $\sqrt{(x,Ax)}$ to be a norm is that the symmetric part of $A$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x,Ax)$ can always be written as $(x,Bx)$ where $B = \frac 12 (A + A^*)$.  Where $A^*$ is the adjoint (conjugate-transpose) of $A$.

For $\Bbb R^n$, it is necessary and sufficient to have $\frac 12 (A + A^*)$ be positive definite.  In order to prove that this is necessary, apply the [Rayleigh-Ritz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) to the matrix $B = \frac 12 (A + A^*)$.